# Data volume testing

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I had requirement to test volume of the database how can I do it? Anybody can help with any web source with practical approach? My database is hosted on AWS ([Aurora PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/))

Comment: What do you mean by volume?

Comment: The amount of data in the database as rows .

Comment: Maximum number of rows depends on the DB engine and (probably) the resources you have https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716470 I would say your question as it is now is too broad. If you could state the problem using the terms of your domain, the strategies you have thought/tried, and additional information, the contributors could suggest better a solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Write a test (in code) that does a query to the database. Select the count to check the number of records.

Reads:

- Learn how to use a database and SQL: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql
- How to get the count with SQL: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php
- More database test scenarios: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/etl_testing/etl_testing_scenarios.htm